# Android position: absolute shouldn't be cut off within a container with border

Tags: android, react-native

This question is duplicate of https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12534. I'm posting it because there is no better solution to resolve this issue.

In iOS it is working fine on the other hand in android there is an issue.

[image]

[image]

Here is my code which will better understand you guys.

```
//Confirm Popup component

import React from 'react';
import { Modal, Text, View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

//Components
import { Card, CardSection, Button } from '../common';

const ConfirmPopup = ({ children, onAccept, onDecline, visible }) => {
   const { textStyle, containerStyle } = styles;
   return (
      <Modal
         visible={visible}
         transparent
         animationType="slide"
         onRequestClose={()=>{alert('Please Select One Of Them')}}
      >
         <View style={containerStyle}>
            <Card style={{position:'relative'}}>
               <Card>
                  <CardSection>
                     <Text style={textStyle}>{children}</Text>
                  </CardSection>
               </Card>
               <Card>
                  <CardSection style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
                     <Button
                        onPress={onAccept}
                        style={{marginHorizontal:5}}
                     >
                        Yes
                     </Button>
                     <Button
                        onPress={onDecline}
                        style={{ marginHorizontal: 5 }}
                     >
                        No
                     </Button>
                  </CardSection>
               </Card>
               <View style={styles.iconWrapper}>
                  <Image source={require('../../assets/img/close.png')} style={styles.iconStyle} />
               </View>
            </Card>
         </View>
      </Modal>
   )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   containerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.75)',
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent:'center'
   },
   textStyle: {
      fontSize: 18,
      fontWeight:'bold'
   },
   iconWrapper: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: -12,
      right:-6
   },
   iconStyle:{
      height: 30,
      width:30
   }
})
```

Comment: Can you add the code to generate this issue?

Comment: @PritishVaidya I have added my code.

Comment: If I'm not wrong you have to add a overflow 'visible' in the style of the parent view which is cutting the child view.